# "Order something done" for "Order something to be done"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

As far as your variety of English goes, can the verbal turn "order something done" be used interchangeably with "order something to be done"?

> "We [ordered this item sent](http://reviews.walmart.com/1336/16352478/kodak-easyshare-c1550-16mp-digital-camera-bundle-w-5x-optical-zoom-3-0-lcd-display-blue-reviews/reviews.htm?sort=rating&dir=asc) to our local store."
>
> "I [ordered this item sent](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560852127) to my son in Utah."
>
> "I [ordered this item delivered](http://www.feefo.com/GB/en/reviews/Flowers-Direct_FLOWERSDIRECT/?id=112560&servicefeedbackid=8423884) to my girlfriend's workplace."
>
> "Yemen [ordered him caught](http://firstread.nbcnews.com/_news/2013/06/06/18805392-house-gop-wants-holder-to-testify-again-on-press-monitoring) dead or alive."

Comment: The cases with the catenations with the verbs 'need' and 'want' (meaning 'need' as in 'need to be') have been covered before. 'Order X V-ed' (eg order the package sent) is quite common on the internet; it is an obvious elision of 'order X to be V-ed'. It seems more acceptable with some X's and V's (and perhaps adverbials) than others (I ordered him shot; ?/*I ordered the ice creams brought immediately; *I ordered the goods purchased.)

Comment: These are two different constructions. If somebody said *"I need this item delivered immediately",* parallel to your first four examples, it would sound perfectly normal (even though they've left out the verb *"to be"*). If somebody said *"This item needs delivered immediately",* parallel to your last three examples, it would sound wrong.